# I want disable the backspace and delete button in input field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

this is my component code

```
<input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input UIInputStyling" id="inputTextId"  value="" placeholder="Search List.."  onkeyup="{!c.onSearch}"  onkeydown="{!c.disableBackspace}"/>
```

this is controller.js

```
disableBackspace : function(component, event, helper) {
    if(event.keyCode == 8){
        return false;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike normal event handlers, if you want to stop an event from taking effect, you can't "return false", but instead need to prevent the event's default action:

```
disableBackspace : function(component, event, helper) {
    if(event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```